# How to Decipher this Handwritten Word

Tags: handwriting

Trying to understand the spelling of the handwritten word, likely a family name

Writing  is found on the leather inside a police holster, assumed to be done by a German individual about 1933-1934. My guess is the word is "Yarap" or "Warap" but my confidence is low as I am not familiar with this style of handwriting. Thank you in advance for your help.

[image]

Comment: I cannot read it easily but that's definitely Sütterlin.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to read *medot*. I'm not sure about the first two letters, but the last three are clear. Very likely it is not a name, since names are usually capitalized, and the first letter is not a capital letter. Maybe the beginning of the word is missing?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is a name, written in Sütterlin (although Sütterlin would have much sharper points, but my guess is that is due to the writng implement)

Letters (read down)

1. **D** (my guess is that there is a big loop barely visible). the main problem here is that it begins with a  downstroke, no Sütterlin letter does that, and my guess is that a very small upstroke was simply left out -> **D / N**
2. **y / r** ? completely unclear and smudged
3. **c / n** ?
4. **d /o** ?
5. **o /d** ?
6. **r /y /s** ? very sloppy any way

followed by 2364 (if the '23' are not digits, i do not know what it might be) - the joining of the 2 and 3 leaves open the possibility of the writer joining unjoined (such as uppercase) letters - so 6th could then be, for instance, a **P**

If you have no further context about the holster (or other known samples in the same hand) i think this will be a wild goose chase. The writing is cramped and faded, my grandmother had problems reading her own script from school-days - Sütterlin can be very multivariate